# Solve recurrence equation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve recurrence equation: $$\frac{y_{t+2}-y_{t+1}}{y_{t+1}} = 0.995 \frac{y_{t+1}-y_{t}}{y_{t}} $$

A friend gave me this question, but I'm not familiar with recurrence equations.

I can solve it for $$k_t := \frac{y_{t+1}-y_t}{y_t} = \frac{y_{t+1}}{y_t}-1$$ but this doesn't give me a closed form for $y_t.$

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c=0.995$. Since you've already no doubt obtained $k_t=k_0 c^t$ so $\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_t}=1+k_0 c^t$, we get $y_t=y_0\prod_{i=0}^{t-1}(1+k_0 c^{i-1})$, $k_0$ of course being $\frac{y_1}{y_0}-1$. (Unsurprisingly, the original recursion relation's general solution requires the first two terms to become particular.)

Answer (score 0):

If
$\dfrac{y_{t+2}-y_{t+1}}{y_{t+1}} 
= a \dfrac{y_{t+1}-y_{t}}{y_{t}}
$
then
$\dfrac{y_{t+2}}{y_{t+1}}-1 
= a (\dfrac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}-1)
$
or
$\dfrac{y_{t+2}}{y_{t+1}}- a \dfrac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}
=1-a
$.

Let
$x_t = \dfrac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}
$.
Then
$x_{t+1}-ax_t = 1-a$.

Now apply the usual trick
of dividing by $a^{t+1}$.
This becomes
$\dfrac{x_{t+1}}{a^{t+1}}-\dfrac{x_t}{a^t}
 = \dfrac{1-a}{a^{t+1}}
$.

Letting
$z_t = \dfrac{x_t}{a^t}$,
this becomes
$z_{t+1}-z_t
 = \dfrac{1-a}{a^{t+1}}
$.

Summing from
$0$ to $n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
z_n-z_0
&=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}(z_{t+1}-z_t)\\
&=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1-a}{a^{t+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-a}{a}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}(1/a)^t\\
&=\dfrac{1-a}{a}\dfrac{1-(1/a)^n}{1-1/a}\\
&=-1+(1/a)^n\\
\end{array}
$

Working back,
since $z_0 = x_0$,

$\dfrac{x_n}{a^n}
=z_n
=z_0-1+(1/a)^n
=x_0-1+(1/a)^n
$
so
$x_n
=a^n(x_0-1)+1
$.

We can now get $y_m$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{y_m}{y_0}
&=\prod_{n=0}^{m-1} \dfrac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{m-1} (a^n(x_0-1)+1)\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{m-1} (a^n((y_1/y_0)-1)+1)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$y_m
=y_0\prod_{n=0}^{m-1} (a^n((y_1/y_0)-1)+1)
$.

Note:
Nothing original here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $w_t:=\dfrac{y_{t+1}-y_t}{y_t}$. The recurrence says

$$w_{t+1}=aw_t$$ and $$w_t=a^tw_0.$$

Now we solve the second recurrence

$$y_{t+1}=(w_t+1)y_t=(a^tw_0+1)y_t$$

with

$$y_t=y_0\prod_{s=1}^t(a^sw_0+1).$$

As far as I know, there is no simpler form.